# How To Cut/Shave Existing Drop In Sink To Fit New Faucets

Tags: water, bathroom-fixtures

Old but very customized Master bathroom remodel (circa 1992)included twin drop-in sinks & exclusive use of Hardin polish brass fixtures. Hardin now long out of business. Want to replace with new bathroom fixtures. When installed over tile in 1992, the rear rims were installed such that there is just a 2 inch space between the sink rears & the tile back splash---which worked then & left just enough space (the 2 inch gap) for the Harden spouts to fit in. Today's replacement hardware requires more. Have found suitable faucets with a circular base that are 2 1/8 inches in diameter. Is there a way to cut/shave/sand paper (or any idea) the rears of the existing sink overlaps to create space to fit in the new faucets? Trying to keep this a low cost project and do not want to replace existing sinks, counter & backsplash tile

Comment: A picture would help. How much could you gain by removing sink and trimming cut out in the front so that sink could shift forward a bit?

Comment: Thank-you for the reply!! Unfortunately cannot move the two sinks toward the front to create more space in the rear. The rounded edge of the drop-in sinks were literally placed up to the edge of the curved, wrap-around counter tile in the front. Obviously did not recognize this issue when buying this home many years ago.

Comment: A photograph would really help.   Agree with the other answer(s) that grinding/drilling your sink may expose you to rust, or permanent damage of the sink.

**You should be able to find a different faucet that has less than 2" radius** between the pivot-axis (center) and the outer diameter of the taps (handles).   Does something like this fit in the space?  [link](https://www.us.kohler.com/webassets/kpna/catalog/pdf/en/K-14406-3_spec.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

What is the material of the drop-in sinks? If it is porcelain on cast iron grinding would expose cast iron which would rust. I suppose you could paint it, but this probably would rust through. If the sinks are solid ceramic you might be able to grind it away with a diamond wheel on an angle grinder or diamond bit on a high speed rotary tool.

I think it would be easier to cut off parts of the flanges on the new faucets. Would you have to cut off parts on both sides of the flanges? If you could confine the cutting to one side (the back), then it would be against the back-splash and would not visible. Of course you want to leave enough flange to seal.